# Mounting a remote folder using cifs

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

My university allows me to connect to my school folder using mount and this is what they suggest I should add to my fstab file:

```
//servername/uni-user /home/myusername/sharedfolder smbfs noauto,username=uni-user,user,rw 0 0
```

And because smbfs is not available anymore at Ubuntu 14.04, I've installed cifs-utils and changed the fstab line to be as following:

```
//servername/uni-user /home/myusername/sharedfolder cifs noauto,username=uni-user,user,rw 0 0
```

Now when I write mount folder, it says timeout error.
My question is, is there anything else I should change in the fstab line other than the name of the mounting utility? Are the parameters at the end of the line still relevant between smbfs and cifs?

I've tried mounting using the command:

```
/home/myusername/sharedfolder
```

Comment: That is not a command, it's a directory. What is the `servername`? Is it an IP or a name? Does it contain spaces? Is the server accessible from your home network? What happens if you `ping  servername`?

Comment: Excuse the silly question, but you did not literally use "//servername/uni-user /home/myusername/sharedfolder" in the fstab file, did you?

Comment: @JacobVlijm, I am new to Lunix, but not that new to computers :)

Comment: @terdon it is a subdomain name, and it is pinging well.

Comment: @Bishoy so it was a silly question ;)

Comment: don't worry @JacobVlijm, I will soon do something silly like that as a newbie, you just didn't bust me this time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this for my part, in fstab:

```
//192.168.1.2/Series /home/user/Series cifs _netdev,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials     0     0
```

with this in smbcredentials

```
username=admin
password=passeadmin
```

Comment: so you suggest I replace `noauto,username=myuser,rw 00` by `_netdev,credentials=/home/user.myuser 0 0`?
I will try that, can you explain what those params mean? sorry I am totally new to that world.

Comment: It is working now after this change, but now I have a new issue, everything is done using root user and the files are not accessible for my normal user. And quick solution? otherwise I will start new question.

Comment: what kind of user did you put in smbcredentials ?